# Java - How to import external packages?

Tags: java, package

I'm still relatively new to Java. I've tried searching for a solution, but I think I don't know enough Java yet to even know exactly what I should be searching for.

I wanted to try playing around with voice recognition, so I downloaded CMU's Sphinx-4 source code and compiled it. Once I had everything working I was able to run the included demos just fine. Next, I created a directory (/Jarvis/) for my code in the directory which holds the Sphinx-4 directory. Within the Sphinx-4 source directory there's a long chain of directories leading to the demos I've played with (/Sphinx4-1.0beta6/src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/). In the demo folder is a HelloWorld directory containing source code for a simple program to use the Sphinx-4 functions. My first goal is to get a copy of this demo working in the directory I have set up for my own code. So I've made a copy of the HelloWorld files and placed them in my Jarvis directory. Renamed and changed the code so that everything which used to be HelloWorld is now Jarvis. Unfortunately the problem I have is not as simple as naming problems, but the paths to find the packages.

With Java, I've mostly only ever used a simple "javac example.java" command to compile code in the past. I'm guessing I might need something more in this case, but I'm not sure exactly what. When trying to compile in this way I get the errors:

```
Jarvis.java:15: error: package edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util does not exist
import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
                                   ^
Jarvis.java:16: error: package edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer does not exist
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
                                ^
Jarvis.java:17: error: package edu.cmu.sphinx.result does not exist
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
                            ^
Jarvis.java:18: error: package edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props does not exist
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;
                                ^
Jarvis.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        ConfigurationManager cm;
        ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationManager
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(args[0]);
                     ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationManager
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(Jarvis.class.getResource("jarvis.config.xml"));
                     ^
  symbol:   class ConfigurationManager
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        ^
  symbol:   class Recognizer
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Recognizer
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
        ^
  symbol:   class Microphone
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Microphone
  location: class Jarvis
Jarvis.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
            Result result = recognizer.recognize();
            ^
  symbol:   class Result
  location: class Jarvis
12 errors
```

So I'm looking to include those missing packages. I understand it has to do with the how the paths are defined in the code, but I don't know enough about Java yet to know exactly how to define those paths. Am I suppose to change something more in the code? Should I be preforming the compile differently? Just a push in the right direction would be useful.

Below I've included the 4 files which originally came from the HelloWorld demo which I've made the slight naming modifications to.

Thank you for your time!

Jarvis.java:

```
package jarvis.jarvis;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;


/**
 * A simple HelloWorld demo showing a simple speech application built using Sphinx-4. This application uses the Sphinx-4
 * endpointer, which automatically segments incoming audio into utterances and silences.
 */
public class Jarvis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurationManager cm;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(args[0]);
        } else {
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(Jarvis.class.getResource("jarvis.config.xml"));
        }

        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        recognizer.allocate();

        // start the microphone or exit if the programm if this is not possible
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
        if (!microphone.startRecording()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
            recognizer.deallocate();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Say: (Good morning | Hello) ( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | Philip | Rita | Will )");

        // loop the recognition until the programm exits.
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

            Result result = recognizer.recognize();

            if (result != null) {
                String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
                System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + '\n');
            } else {
                System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

jarvis.config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
   Sphinx-4 Configuration file
-->

<!-- ******************************************************** -->
<!--  an4 configuration file                             -->
<!-- ******************************************************** -->

<config>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- frequently tuned properties                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <property name="logLevel" value="WARNING"/>

    <property name="absoluteBeamWidth"  value="-1"/>
    <property name="relativeBeamWidth"  value="1E-80"/>
    <property name="wordInsertionProbability" value="1E-36"/>
    <property name="languageWeight"     value="8"/>

    <property name="frontend" value="epFrontEnd"/>
    <property name="recognizer" value="recognizer"/>
    <property name="showCreations" value="false"/>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- word recognizer configuration                            -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="recognizer" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer">
        <property name="decoder" value="decoder"/>
        <propertylist name="monitors">
            <item>accuracyTracker </item>
            <item>speedTracker </item>
            <item>memoryTracker </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Decoder   configuration                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="decoder" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder">
        <property name="searchManager" value="searchManager"/>
    </component>

    <component name="searchManager"
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="linguist" value="flatLinguist"/>
        <property name="pruner" value="trivialPruner"/>
        <property name="scorer" value="threadedScorer"/>
        <property name="activeListFactory" value="activeList"/>
    </component>


    <component name="activeList"
             type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.PartitionActiveListFactory">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="absoluteBeamWidth" value="${absoluteBeamWidth}"/>
        <property name="relativeBeamWidth" value="${relativeBeamWidth}"/>
    </component>

    <component name="trivialPruner"
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.pruner.SimplePruner"/>

    <component name="threadedScorer"
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer">
        <property name="frontend" value="${frontend}"/>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The linguist  configuration                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="flatLinguist"
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="grammar" value="jsgfGrammar"/>
        <property name="acousticModel" value="wsj"/>
        <property name="wordInsertionProbability"
                value="${wordInsertionProbability}"/>
        <property name="languageWeight" value="${languageWeight}"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Grammar  configuration                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammar">
        <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
        <property name="grammarLocation"
             value="resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/jarvis/"/>
        <property name="grammarName" value="jarvis"/>
    <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Dictionary configuration                            -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="dictionary"
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary">
        <property name="dictionaryPath"
     value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d"/>
        <property name="fillerPath"
     value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/noisedict"/>
        <property name="addSilEndingPronunciation" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowMissingWords" value="false"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The acoustic model configuration                         -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <component name="wsj"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.TiedStateAcousticModel">
        <property name="loader" value="wsjLoader"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>

    <component name="wsjLoader" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
        <property name="location" value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The unit manager configuration                           -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="unitManager"
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager"/>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The frontend configuration                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="frontEnd" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
        <propertylist name="pipeline">
            <item>microphone </item>
            <item>preemphasizer </item>
            <item>windower </item>
            <item>fft </item>
            <item>melFilterBank </item>
            <item>dct </item>
            <item>liveCMN </item>
            <item>featureExtraction </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The live frontend configuration                          -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <component name="epFrontEnd" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
        <propertylist name="pipeline">
            <item>microphone </item>
            <item>dataBlocker </item>
            <item>speechClassifier </item>
            <item>speechMarker </item>
            <item>nonSpeechDataFilter </item>
            <item>preemphasizer </item>
            <item>windower </item>
            <item>fft </item>
            <item>melFilterBank </item>
            <item>dct </item>
            <item>liveCMN </item>
            <item>featureExtraction </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The frontend pipelines                                   -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="dataBlocker" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.DataBlocker">
        <!--<property name="blockSizeMs" value="10"/>-->
    </component>

    <component name="speechClassifier"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.SpeechClassifier">
        <property name="threshold" value="13"/>
    </component>

    <component name="nonSpeechDataFilter"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.NonSpeechDataFilter"/>

    <component name="speechMarker"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.SpeechMarker" >
        <property name="speechTrailer" value="50"/>
    </component>


    <component name="preemphasizer"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.filter.Preemphasizer"/>

    <component name="windower"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.window.RaisedCosineWindower">
    </component>

    <component name="fft"
            type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.transform.DiscreteFourierTransform">
    </component>

    <component name="melFilterBank"
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.frequencywarp.MelFrequencyFilterBank">
    </component>

    <component name="dct"
            type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.transform.DiscreteCosineTransform"/>

    <component name="liveCMN"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.LiveCMN"/>

    <component name="featureExtraction"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.DeltasFeatureExtractor"/>

    <component name="microphone"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone">
        <property name="closeBetweenUtterances" value="false"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    <!--  monitors                                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->

    <component name="accuracyTracker"
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.BestPathAccuracyTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <property name="showAlignedResults" value="false"/>
        <property name="showRawResults" value="false"/>
    </component>

    <component name="memoryTracker"
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
    <property name="showSummary" value="false"/>
    <property name="showDetails" value="false"/>
    </component>

    <component name="speedTracker"
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <property name="frontend" value="${frontend}"/>
    <property name="showSummary" value="true"/>
    <property name="showDetails" value="false"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    <!--  Miscellaneous components                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->

    <component name="logMath" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.util.LogMath">
        <property name="logBase" value="1.0001"/>
        <property name="useAddTable" value="true"/>
    </component>

</config>
```

jarvis.gram:

```
#JSGF V1.0;

/**
 * JSGF Grammar for Hello World example
 */

grammar jarvis;

public <greet> = (Good morning | Hello) ( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | Philip | Rita | Will );
```

jarvis.Manifest

```
Main-Class: jarvis.Jarvis
Class-Path: ../sphinx4-1.0beta6/lib/sphinx4.jar ../sphinx4-1.0beta6/lib/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler uses the "class path" to look for required libraries. There are many ways to set the class path: one is using the CLASSPATH environment variable, another is using the `-classpath` command line switch. In summary you could compile with:

```
javac -classpath path/to/sphinx.jar jarvis/Jarvis.java
```

You'll find the full documentation in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Another thing: your Jarvis class declares that it's in a package called `jarvis.jarvis`, so the fully qualified name of the class would be `jarvis.jarvis.Jarvis` ... not sure that's what you intend.

Answer (score 3):

Use "-classpath" option to tell `javac` where to find all needed classes.

```
javac -classpath lib/blablabla.jar;lib/foobar.jar
```

[Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).