# How to import SwingX without IDE

Tags: java, import, package, external, swingx

This is my first post so please don't bite my head off!

I have found this:
[Java - How to import external packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153261/java-how-to-import-external-packages)

and this:
[how to include libraries in java without using an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112607/how-to-include-libraries-in-java-without-using-an-ide)

but I'm still lost!

I have downloaded the file swingx-1.6.zip to my ~/Downloads folder (ubuntu) then unzipped it so I now have ~/Downloads/swingx-1.6
In this folder is swingx-1.6.jar which appears to have the class I want (JXPanel)

Then I ran this in a terminal:
`javac -classpath :~/Downloads/swingx-1.6/swingx-1.6.jar Panels.java`
were Panels.java is the class file which is (or will soon be) dependent on JXPanel.

I'm getting compile errors though!

```
Panels.java:6: package org.jdesktop.swingx does not exist
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXPanel;
                      ^
1 error
```

My question is: Have I included the right files in the `-classpath` command? and Have I used the right `import` command?...

sorry for being such a noob,
I really don't want to migrate to an IDE. I was just getting the hang of where I am now lol
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO :)  Can't answer your question immediately, but I had to chime in and recommend using an IDE...Java development is a hell of a lot easier with an environment.  And Eclipse is free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to remove the ':' and also to use the full path, not ~/, because some software does not resolve it.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't the ':' (lost the default java packages when I removed that) but it was the '~/'. Appears to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

Your import seems to be correct.
I suspect your issue is the ':' at the beginning. ':' only needed as a separator, and having it at the start of the path may be confusing the compiler.
Try it without the ':'.

To be honest if you are learning java an IDE will make that process easier.